# Is it actually a memory leak in unmounted React component?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Is it actually a memory leak when you are setting the state of an unmounted component from promise just once? Shouldn't it be cleaned up automatically after that so that you don't have any leak?
I'm talking about this warning:

`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

I can see how it's a leak if you forget to unsubscribe from continuous subscription that holds reference of your memory. But if it's just resolves once and stops, how is it a leak?
I can see people checking for mount before setting the state, but does it actually matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React only knows a state update is occurring on an unmounted component, but not the reason why. While it may not actually be a memory leak, it *is* a leak, meaning, something wasted, like computing cycles.

It's only a warning, and from what I understand, will only log in non-production builds. In this case if it is simply a latent state update from a single network request it might not be an issue. I guess if it actually matters is really up to you to decide.